# Attach Spring Multipart object to a Java mail object

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail, multipart

I am trying to create an automated mailing system. As attachments what I get in return calling the methods of the component, which I don't have access to it's source code is a Springframework MultipartFile object. Is there any way to attach this object in a Java mail object or is there a way to convert a Springframework MultipartFile object to javax.mail.Multipart object ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look here:

http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-send-e-mail-with-attachments

At line 55 they have an example of how you can do this.  You need to implement InputStreamSource - but its very straight forward.

```
 messageHelper.addAttachment(attachName, new InputStreamSource() {

                        @Override
                        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
                            return attachFile.getInputStream();
                        }
                    });
                }
```

messageHelper is a MimeMessageHelper